# Random errors in XML-XSL transformation in tomcat web app

Tags: java, xml, xslt, tomcat, transformation

Im getting this error randomly in the web application which does the XML-XSL transformation. Same data when reloaded exception does not occur.

----------error 1

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7 >= 7  
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.startElement(SAXDriver.java:804)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseElement(XmlParser.java:1037)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDocument(XmlParser.java:416)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:167)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)  
at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault.getDTM(DTMManagerDefault.java:437)  
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:699)  
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1284)  
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1262)  
at org.apache.taglibs.xtags.xslt.StyleTag.doEndTag(StyleTag.java:157)  
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.chart.newleafmodel.tabdetail_jsp._jspService(tabdetail_jsp.java:698)  
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)  
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)
```

-----------------------------------error 2

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 >= 5  
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:427)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.startElement(SAXDriver.java:804)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseElement(XmlParser.java:1037)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.parseDocument(XmlParser.java:416)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlParser.doParse(XmlParser.java:167)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.SAXDriver.parse(SAXDriver.java:320)  
at gnu.xml.aelfred2.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:294)  
at org.apache.xml.dtm.ref.DTMManagerDefault.getDTM(DTMManagerDefault.java:437)  
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:699)  
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1284)  
at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1262)  
at org.apache.taglibs.xtags.xslt.StyleTag.doEndTag(StyleTag.java:157)  
at org.apache.jsp.jsp.chart.newleafmodel.tabdetail_jsp._jspService(tabdetail_jsp.java:698)  
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)  
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:386)  
... 29 more
```

---

Is it anyway related to the xml parser which we configured for our webapps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the exception is thrown from the XML parser, it is of course related to the parser. Why don't you try with Xerces instead?

Comment: yes the problems in the xml parser, there was some gnu xml parser jar which was renamed. With eclipse it was found and removed.